# Iterate through class properties

Tags: vb.net, class, reflection, properties

I have a VB.NET class called ticket that has several public properties of type 'field'. I would like to have a way that I can iterate through all of these properties (with a for each) and perform a specific task on each of them. I thought that maybe the best way was to create a list(Of field) and fill the list with the 'field' properties of that class. What I don't know how to do is get the properties into the list dynamically so that if I add properties in the future I don't have to type them into the list manually. Any thoughts on how I might do this? I tried searching for and found some examples of using reflection but I could only figure out how to get at the name of the property and not the property itself.

Here is an example of a class:

```
Public Class ticket
    Public Property location As New field
    Public Property user As New field
    Public Property callType As New field
    Public Property dateOfCall As New field
    Public Property tech As New field
    Public Property description As New field

    Public Property myFields As New List(Of field)

'What if field had a property of value and I wanted to increment all of the fields    in this class by one

Public Sub plusOne()
    For Each x As field In myFields()
        x.value += 1
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which just means inspecting the types in an assembly. You can do this via the [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) namespace.

See the following article on the msdn magazine for examples of reflection in VB.Net:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx

An example of iterating over the members of a type in that article is as follows:

```
Dim t As Type = GetType(AcmeCorp.BusinessLogic.Customer)
For Each member As MemberInfo In t.GetMembers
  Console.WriteLine(member.Name)
Next
```

Comment: How would I achieve something like names.add(member)? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers have said, you need to use System.Reflection to get the properties of the class. Then check the property is the type that you want.

Hopefully this should give you what you want. If you run the code you will see that it only takes the properties of the specified type. If you want to have all properties, remove the where statement on the for each loop.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    ' Create a list to hold your properties
    Dim myList As New List(Of MyProperty)

    ' check each property for its type using the where statement below. Change integer to "Field" in your case
    For Each el In GetType(Test).GetProperties.Where(Function(p) p.PropertyType = GetType(Integer))
        ' add each matching property to the list
        myList.Add(New MyProperty With {.Name = el.Name, .GetMethod = el.GetGetMethod(), .SetMethod = el.GetSetMethod()})
        Console.WriteLine(el.Name & " has been added to myList")
    Next

    Console.Read()
End Sub

Public Class MyProperty
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property GetMethod As MethodInfo
    Public Property SetMethod As MethodInfo
End Class

Public Class Test
    Private var1 As String
    Private var2 As String
    Private var3 As String
    Private var4 As String

    Public Property myInt1 As Integer
    Public Property myInt2 As Integer
    Public Property myInt3 As Integer
    Public Property myInt4 As Integer
End Class
End Module
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this creates a list of objects that are duplicates not the same. So if I did a for each to modify each of the Tests in the list I would not be modifying the properties for the instance of that class.

Comment: Completely off the top of my head, but it should work because the class holds onto the reference. It's something you can try by dumping the code above into a console app. I can't do it atm though otherwise id verify for you

Answer (score 0):

Again as the previous answer - you would use reflection. To call as an example `Add` on a `List(Of T)` I would do this.

```
Public Class Test
  Public Property SomeList As List(Of String)
End Class
```

Then use the following code to call add on a `List(Of String)`

```
Dim pi As PropertyInfo = GetType(Test).GetProperty("SomeList")
Dim mi As MethodInfo = GetType(List(Of String)).GetMethod("Add")
Dim t As New Test()
t.SomeList = New List(Of String)
mi.Invoke(pi.GetValue(t, Nothing), New Object() {"Added through reflection"})
```